# model.matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, regression

there is a data set I am working on which contains only multilevel factors as predictors and a binary response variable. This is currently a data frame. I want to run glmnet on the set so I need to build a model matrix (model.matrix). I read here 
[All Levels of a Factor in a Model Matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r)
that a certain level per factor is taken as level. However, I don't know whether this is because in this case there are numerical and factor variables? In any case, can somebody roughly tell me how i would build a model matrix from the `mtcars` data set from MASS

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, since you have not described the function(s) you are using. My hunch is that you are using one of the "machine learning"--algorithms that require you to deliver separate respone vectors and predictor matrices. (If I'm wrong on this matter, then you definitely need to provide more details.)

Presuming you would use `mpg` as an "outcome" Y-variable, Using only the 2nd and third variables and constructing "dummy variables" only for the first this would be a model.matrix call that could build an appropriate X-object:

```
> model.matrix(~as.factor(cyl)+disp, mtcars[2:3])
                    (Intercept) as.factor(cyl)6 as.factor(cyl)8  disp
Mazda RX4                     1               1               0 160.0
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1               1               0 160.0
Datsun 710                    1               0               0 108.0
Hornet 4 Drive                1               1               0 258.0
Hornet Sportabout             1               0               1 360.0
Valiant                       1               1               0 225.0
Duster 360                    1               0               1 360.0
Merc 240D                     1               0               0 146.7
Merc 230                      1               0               0 140.8
Merc 280                      1               1               0 167.6
Merc 280C                     1               1               0 167.6
Merc 450SE                    1               0               1 275.8
##########Snipped remainder of output.
```

The formula object specifies the nature of model. The (Intercept)-term will be the shared bases level against which all factor variables are referenced.