# R: Is there an equivalent of Stata's ibn. function?

Tags: r, stata

I'm running a model without an intercept, and I only have categorical predictors. I have also included an interaction term between my main predictor and another covariate. But the output shows that for the interaction terms it has a reference group, even though I suppress the intercept. Therefore, I was wondering if `R` has a function equivalent to Statas .ibn function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ibn.` factor-variable operator in Stata enables that all levels of the factor variable are included in the model (the factor variable "loses" its base).

In `R` you can achieve this by resetting the `contrasts` for the factor variables. Here how to do this is described by fabians : [All Levels of a Factor in a Model Matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r)